# Cannot call throwable Swift function from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, throwable

Class is written in Swift,

```
@objc class Test: NSObject {

    @objc func testBoolean() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc func testOptionalBoolean() -> Bool? {
        return true
    }

    @objc func testThrowableBoolean() throws -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc func testThrowableOptionalBoolean() throws -> Bool? {
        return true
    }
}
```

Among these functions only first function is compilable.

#### Other functions compiler errors,

> **testOptionalBoolean**: Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C
>
> **testThrowableBoolean**: Throwing method cannot be marked @objc because it returns a value of type 'Bool'; return 'Void' or a type that bridges to an Objective-C class
>
> **testThrowableOptionalBoolean**: Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C

**What is the proper way to make all of functions available for objc callers?**

Comment: You still want to call these the same way in Swift, right?

Comment: @Sweeper yes offcourse

Comment: Would you mind creating copies of those methods (not copies of their bodies, just the header)? For example, you can write another method `@objc func testOptionalBoolean() -> NSNumber? {
        return testOptionalBoolean().map(NSNumber.init(value:))
    }` But I know that some people doesn't like having two methods with the same name and parameters.

Comment: Return `NSNumber` where compiler complains

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are quite clear:

1. An optional scalar type cannot be used as a return type in ObjC because only objects are `nullable`.
2. To be able to convert a `throw`ing Swift function to the ObjC inout `NSError` syntax the return type must be `AnyObject` (a class) in terms of Swift.

You can replace the `Bool` types with `NSNumber` for example

```
@objc func testOptionalBoolean() -> NSNumber? {
    return true // Yes, returning a Swift Bool is valid
}
```

but even with `NSNumber` the function `testThrowableOptionalBoolean` does not compile because the design of a throwing function is to return a non-optional on success

Comment: What if I want to return a String or Array? Isn't there any generic solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

> [SE-0230](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0230-flatten-optional-try.md) modifies the way `try?` works so that nested optionals are flattened to become regular optionals. This makes it work the same way as optional chaining and conditional typecasts, both of which flatten optionals in earlier Swift versions.

[Hackingwithswift Article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/147/swift-5-is-changing-optional-try)

---

You can create an object as a wrapper.

```swift
@objc class Test: NSObject {

    @objc func testBoolean() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc func testOptionalBoolean() -> BooleanWrapper? {
        return BooleanWrapper(true)
    }

    @objc func testThrowableBoolean() throws -> BooleanWrapper {
        return BooleanWrapper(true)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
if let wrapper = try? test.testThrowableBoolean() {
    print(wrapper.bool)
}
```

**Wrapper**

```
@objc class BooleanWrapper: NSObject {

    let bool: Bool

    init(_ bool: Bool) {
        self.bool = bool
    }
}
```